# Accessing HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name in the DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, structuremap3

I'm going to use the UserName for tracking Created and Modified fields. To do that I have referenced to the System.Web assembly directly inside DbContext:

```
public void auditFields()
 {
            var auditDate = DateTime.Now;
            foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>())
            {
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Detached:
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Unchanged:
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        entry.Entity.CreatedOn = auditDate;
                        entry.Entity.ModifiedOn = auditDate;
                        entry.Entity.CreatedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name ?? "anonymouse";
                        entry.Entity.ModifiedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name ?? "anonymouse";
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        entry.Entity.ModifiedOn = auditDate;
                        entry.Entity.ModifiedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name ?? "anonymouse";
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }
            }
}
```

It works, But it's tightly coupling the DbContext with HttpContext which is not a good idea in case we'll expose the DbContext to a non-web environment.
So I use this way:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext :
        IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>,
        IUnitOfWork
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("ConnectionString")
        {
        }
        public ApplicationDbContext(string userName)
            : base("ConnectionString")
        {
            UserName = userName;
        }
    //Other codes
    public string UserName
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    public void auditFields()
    {
            var auditDate = DateTime.Now;
            foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>())
            {
                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Detached:
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Unchanged:
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        entry.Entity.CreatedOn = auditDate;
                        entry.Entity.ModifiedOn = auditDate;
                        entry.Entity.CreatedBy = UserName ?? "anonymouse";
                        entry.Entity.ModifiedBy = UserName ?? "anonymouse";
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        entry.Entity.ModifiedOn = auditDate;
                        entry.Entity.ModifiedBy = UserName ?? "anonymouse";
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

And in the Ioc config project (I'm using structureMap in another class library):

```
ioc.For<IUnitOfWork>()
                   .HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
                   .Use<ApplicationDbContext>()
                   .Ctor<string>().Is(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

But when I run the application I'll get this error in above line:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

It seems that it can't inject HttpContext.

Any idea?

Comment: "ThreadLocalScoped" sounds suspicious... - I have no idea how your container deals with lifetime, but HttpContext.Current valid only during requests only for threads handling request and it is likely your object is resolved at different time.

Comment: This would be so much simpler with [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di), not to mention type-safe.

Comment: Case in point: here's how much trouble I had doing something similar with Castle Windsor: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10854701/126014

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this link http://techbrij.com/service-layer-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-unit-testing

The Author's solution looks like yours (but he used AutoFac instead of StructureMap). His "trick" to get the "Name" was `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;`

Another thing, IMHO, I think you should use `DateTimeOffSet` instead of `DateTime` for the audit date. Using `DateTimeOffSet` you won't have problems with differents time zone. Like this:

```
DateTimeOffSet auditDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should help

[ASP.NET MVC: HTTPContext and Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877712/asp-net-mvc-httpcontext-and-dependency-injection)

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/08/taking-httpcontext-out-of-mvc-framework.html